# Append window.history.back() URL to pass a variable to previous page

Tags: javascript, html

What little coding experience I have is completely self-taught, and spread over a decade of 'tinkering'. I'm basically a total novice. I've managed to piece the below together from various posts, but now I'm ready to ask for help.

We have a managed **WordPress** website and I don't have access to the webserver, the developers charge very high fees and I'm just trying to save us some money.

I am trying to use **javascript** to send my users back one page, appending a query string that I can then use to test an if statement, which then changes some **CSS** to hide a form and show a success message.

Instead, the result of the below just refreshes 'page 2', appending `"undefined?redirect=successful"` to the URL.

My searching online tells me that it's something to do with ASP.NET, which I don't have. Maybe I'm over-complicating this. Any recommendations on how else I can achieve my end goal?

**On page 1**

```
<script>
function getQueryVariable(variable)
{
       var query = window.location.search.substring(1);
       var vars = query.split("&");
       for (var i=0;i<vars.length;i++) {
               var pair = vars[i].split("=");
               if(pair[0] == variable){return pair[1];}
       }
       return(false);
}

function myFunction() {
var a = getQueryVariable("redirect")
var b = "successful"
if(a.equals(b) == true) {
  var element = document.getElementById("clickdim_form");
            element.classList.add("clickdim_hidden");
            var element = document.getElementById("clickdim_submsg");
            element.classList.add("clickdim_visible");
}

}
window.onload = myFunction;
window.onload = getQueryVariable;
</script>
```

**On page 2**

```
<script>
function myFunction() {location.href = window.history.back()+"?redirect=successful";}
window.onload = myFunction;
</script>
```

Help on this would be greatly appreciated..Thanks

Comment: Does cookie help you?

Comment: `window.history.back()` won't return you an url. It redirects, thats why you got 'undefined'.

Comment: Try window.location.href inside getQueryVariable function.

Comment: Direct access to `window.history.back()` would be a huge privacy vulnerability in the browser API. That's why you cannot read it, just execute it, like @sonic mentioned.

Comment: Thanks @Chaska I've used cookies to solve the problem. Thank you to all who commented!